# easymock - mocking to use anyObject as parma of void setter method

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Using EasyMock, how can I create the mock of the following class's process method? I want to create a mock which can accept any object of type `MyObject.class`.

```
public class Custom {
    public void process(MyObject obj){
        //code
    }
}
```

I know how to do it if the method returns something, but with a `void` method I am not able to get my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to expect a call on a `void` method

```
Custom mock = EasyMock.createMock(Custom.class); // create the mock
mock.process(EasyMock.anyObject(MyObject.class)); // invoke the method
EasyMock.expectLastCall(); // register it as expected
EasyMock.replay(mock); // set the state


mock.process(new MyObject()); // invoke the method in the test

EasyMock.verify(mock); // verify the call
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to mock a `void` method you simply call it on the mock object **before** calling replay.

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    Custom mock = createMock(Custom.class);
    mock.process(any(MyObject.class);
    replay(mock);

    // Your test comes here

    // Optional - check the process was called
    verify(mock);
}
```